# Java server cannot parseFrom protobuf byte[]

Tags: java, post, encoding, protocol-buffers, libcurl

I use libcurl from a c++ client in order to submit post data to a java server.
For some reason, the post data (protobuf SerializeToString) cannot be parsed on the server side.

Here is the client side part:

```
string str;
ProtoBufMessage.SerializeToString(&str);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, str);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, str.size());
```

And here is the Java code on the server:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public @ResponseBody
byte[] updateStatus( @RequestBody byte[] message) {
    try {
       ProtobufMessage pbMessage = ProtobufMessage.parseFrom(message);

    ...

}
```

When I convert the message to a String, I get the following value - "%C3%B4%C3%BA%29%00%00%00%00%00%C3%BD%C3%BD%C3%BD%C3%BD%C2%AB%C2%AB%C2%AB%C2%AB%C2%AB%C2%AB="

However, the client is sending the following value - "\b\x1\x1a\xe\n\x5Hello\x12\x5world"

I believe it is somehow related to the encoding of the transmitted bytes, but how can I control it?

Also, here is the exception i'm getting on the server side, while parsing the message - 
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html), the parameter for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` needs to be a `char*`. You're passing an `std::string`. You don't get a compile error because `curl_easy_setopt` is a c-style vararg function, which has no type checking.

Change the line to:

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, str.data());
```

An additional possible problem here is that libcurl will send the request with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Many web servers will recognize this type and attempt to parse it as form data. You should override `Content-Type` to something like `application/x-protobuf` or maybe just `application/octet-stream` (which means "byte blob") to avoid any problems.

Comment: I changed it to str.data() but the real problem was related to serialization between c++ and java (so I ended up base64-encoding the message). Thanks